# Finding maximum values of a score for a given subject over multiple timepoints

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

To start, here's example data which I'm working with:

```
ID BaselineScore MidScore Final Score
1  x             NA       NA 
1  NA            y        NA
1  NA            NA       z 
2  a             NA       NA 
2  NA            b        NA
2  NA            NA       c
```

What I'd like to accomplish is for a given ID (ID==1,ID==2, etc.), determine which of the three scores (baseline, mid, or final) is greatest (i.e. max(x,y,z), max(a,b,c), etc.). The reason I have NAs is because I used the `spread` function from tidyr (the score variables at a certain time point were originally rows under a more general score variable).

I tried used the base R pmax function, but that only works if you have 'horizontally' aligned values between columns.

Any tips?

Thanks,

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>% gather(Score_type, Score, -ID) %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Score==max(Score, na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: Sounds like you could probably do this without converting your data to the format you have shown here, without `spread`-ing.

Comment: @eipi10, I'm not too familiar with the gather function yet; I'm not sure how to input each of my three score variables into that code you posted.

Comment: You don't need to input the names. Score_type is the new "key" column (the column that will contain the (former) column names of the columns we're melting), and Score is the name of the column that will hold the values in the (former) columns that we're melting. You can use any names you want for these two columns. `-ID` keeps `ID` as an identifier column. If you know how the use `melt` from the `reshape2` package, the equivalent code is `melt(df, id.vars="ID")`.

Comment: @eipi10 Oh wow, that works wonderfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base solution using apply and max and then find the max index.

```
df <- read.csv(text="ID,BaselineScore,MidScore,Final Score
1,1,NA,NA
1,NA,2,NA
1,NA,NA,3
2,7,NA,NA
2,NA,6,NA
2,NA,NA,5")

fun_base <- function() {
    lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) {
        tmp <- apply(x[-1], 2, max, na.rm=TRUE)
        tmp[which.max(tmp)]
    })
}

fun_dplyr <- function() {
    df %>% 
        gather(Score_type, Score, -ID) %>% 
        group_by(ID) %>% 
        filter(Score==max(Score, na.rm=TRUE))
}

microbenchmark(
    fun_base(),
    fun_dplyr(),
    times=50L)

#Unit: microseconds
#        expr    min     lq     mean  median     uq    max neval
#  fun_base()  590.6  666.6  728.842  709.85  789.1 1060.1    50
# fun_dplyr() 2110.3 2318.3 2533.324 2442.75 2639.5 3663.4    50
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `coalesce` the columns together and then get the `max` by 'ID'

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   transmute(ID, newCol = coalesce(BaselineScore, MidScore, FinalScore)) %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(newCol = max(newCol))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
#      ID newCol
#   <int>  <chr>
#1     1      z
#2     2      c
```

---

Or another option is to use `pmax` and `max`

```
df %>% 
 transmute(ID, newCol = pmax(BaselineScore, MidScore, FinalScore, na.rm =TRUE)) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 summarise(newCol = max(newCol))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. However, I get NAs for the newCol when I run it on my actual data. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: @lecreprays  I tested on your example and it is working fine.  You may have to check the `str(yourdata)`.  Are those columns `numieric` or `character` or `factor` class?

Comment: my score variables are numeric, and my ID variable is an integer class variable.

Comment: @lecreprays  Based on the info you provided, it should work as I tested it.