# Finding parallel maxima between columns only when a key column is NA

Tags: r, max, data-manipulation

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43509230/finding-maximum-values-of-a-score-for-a-given-subject-over-multiple-timepoints) a few days ago, which addressed how to find parallel maxima given the presence of NAs in relevant columns. However, I realized that I was not quite asking the right question; what I'd really like to accomplish is to be able to find the parallel maxima of a row, but only if a key column equals NA.

Here's same example data:

```
df1
ID Score1 Score2 Score3
1  2      3      1
2  5      1      2
3  1      6      8
4  9      10     NA
```

Let the Score3 variable represent this'key' column. That is, I would like to calculate a new variable, Score4, which represents the maximum score among the 3 score variables only when Score3=NA, and otherwise (when Score 3 does not equal NA) takes on the values of Score3.

Here the result I'd like to see, after apply some function `FUN`:

```
df2<-FUN(df1)
df2
ID Score1 Score2 Score3 Score4
1  2      3      1       1
2  5      1      2       2 
3  1      6      8       8
4  9      10     NA      10
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
df1 <- data.table(ID = c(1,2,3,4), Score1 = c(2,5,1,9), Score2 = c(3,1,6,10), Score3 = c(1,2,8,NA))

df1[, Score4 := ifelse(is.na(Score3), max(Score1, Score2), Score3), by = 1:nrow(df1)]

df1

   ID Score1 Score2 Score3 Score4
1:  1      2      3      1      1
2:  2      5      1      2      2
3:  3      1      6      8      8
4:  4      9     10     NA     10
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I haven't used data.table before, I when I try to run it on my actual data, I get this error: unused argument (by = 1:nrow(df)). I'm sure I made a simple error, but I'm not sure where. Any tips?

Comment: I am not sure why you'll get that. Did you try running exactly what I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, here's the solution I came up with, as well:

```
df1<-df1%>%
mutate(Score4_a=pmax(Score1,Score2,Score3,na.rm=T))%>%
mutate(Score4_b=replace(Score3,is.na(Score3)==T,Score4_a))
```